# Junit skip call to a function into another question

Tags: java, testing, junit

I want to test a function in my code. This function calls another function in the same class but in my test I don't want to call it (I don't need it). Somehow, my test always goes into that inner function and makes errors. Is there any means to "skip" the call to that inner function ?

**Here's an example :**

```java
void function1() { 
    if(condition == true) {
        variable1 = function2()
    }
}

Object function2() {
    //Do something
    return Object;
}
```

Is there a way to avoid calling function 2 ?

Thank you.

Comment: if you don't need it, why is that call in your method? either you need to test it, or it shouldn't be there, or your test is pointless

Comment: If a function call is throwing erros in a junit, you should be fixing the errors instead of skipping the function call. You might need to refactor the `function2` a bit so that it is unit testable.

Answer (score 1):

First you should consider fixing those errors thrown from `function2()`.
If however you want to test the `function1()` isolated then the behavior you are describing is called `Test Doubles`. One kind of those test doubles is `Mocking` where you can drive the behavior of a class or a method.

There are frameworks doing this such as [Mockito](https://site.mockito.org/), but of course you can solve that problem on your own not depending on frameworks.

For example if you use Mockito you should end up mocking the `function2()` method like this

```
YouClassName mockedClass = mock(YouClassName.class);
when(mockedClass.function2()).thenReturn(new Object()); //you can of course return anything here
```

Its pretty common to test functions in isolation but in times where are dependencies between objects. If there are no dependencies you should probably consider not using test doubles (unless you are sure what you are doing).

Answer (score 0):

Frameworks such as Mockito offer concepts such as [spies](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-spy). Using a Mockito spy, you can gain full control over which methods get invoked.

But: you only do that for very specific cases.

When you have a hard time testing your production code, then most likely: because you have written hard to test code.

Thus: you could try to use a spy here, but I would rather advice to step back and re-think what exactly you intend to do here.